# How to order gt in descending order

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

Could someone show me how I can order the following gt table by year, month, week, and SampleDate?  I would like the most recent year to be at the top of the table, which in this case is 2013. Example and screenshot below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2012", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 0), W = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), S = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), LF = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), week = c("01", "02", "02", "01", 
"01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", 
"01"), month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January"
)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

a |>
  mutate(SampleDate = as.character(SampleDate)) |>
  group_by(year, month, week, SampleDate) |>
  summarise(across(c(W, F, LF, S), sum)) |>
  gt() |>
  summary_rows(
    columns = -SampleDate,
    fns =  list(label = "Total", fn = "sum"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `arrange` the data first as per your preference before passing it to `gt()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

a |>
  mutate(SampleDate = as.character(SampleDate)) |>
  group_by(year, month, week, SampleDate) |>
  summarise(across(c(W, F, LF, S), sum)) |>
  arrange(desc(year), desc(week)) |>
  gt() |>
  summary_rows(
    columns = -SampleDate,
    fns =  list(label = "Total", fn = "sum"))
```

[image]